# After minting my collection appears with name "Collection NFT"

Tags: solana, candy-machine

I'm using candy-machine v2 to mint my NFT collection. I set up everything correctly and tested a basic minting. Everything seems fine, all metadata is correct. However the collection appears with the name "Collection NFT" in my Phantom wallet.

[image: Collection name]

I generated the json's correctly however it shows up as Collection NFT.

```
{
 "name": "test #0",
  "symbol": "test",
  "description": "testing",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 1000,
  "image": "0.png",
  "external_url": "test.com",
  "edition": 0,
  "creator": "tester",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "a",
      "value": "a"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "b",
      "value": "b"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "c",
      "value": "c"
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "0.png",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "category": "image",
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "my address here",
        "share": 100
      }
    ]
  },
  "collection": {
    "name": "test collection",
    "family": "test collection"
  }
}
```

I want my collection to be named "test collection" in this case. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify your collection on Metaplex.

https://collections.metaplex.com/

you have to use your "update authority" account for verify.